# Rails stops sending mails with deliver_later after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rails-activejob

I'm sending mails from a Rails application using GMail. When I start the server, everything works fine and Rails sends mails both by using deliver_now and deliver_later. However after some time (about 5h or 50 mails, exact numbers missing), mails sent via deliver_later do not get sent any more. Mails sent by deliver_now are still getting sent.

- The SMTP configuration must be correct because mails are still being sent
- For the same reason, it cannot be a rate limit
- The deliver_later method works and sends several mails before the problem occurs
- Once the problem occurs, no more mails get sent at all using deliver_later

How can I debug this? There are no erros in the logs.

**Edit**

Here's an extract from the logs. When the mail does not get sent, all I see is:

```
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.356376 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] Started POST "/participations" for client-ip-hidden at 2019-11-08 13:43:39 +0000
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.360089 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] Processing by ParticipationsController#create as HTML
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.360573 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token-hidden==", "participation"=>{"event_id"=>"e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1", "details"=>""}, "commit"=>"Teilnahme erstellen"}
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.367662 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   Event Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.373298 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.381975 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   User Exists (2.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "participations" ON "users"."id" = "participations"."user_id" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.386523 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.390719 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   CACHE Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.396173 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]   Participation Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "participations" ("user_id", "event_id", "status", "details", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["status", 2], ["details", ""], ["created_at", "2019-11-08 13:43:39.392358"], ["updated_at", "2019-11-08 13:43:39.392358"]]
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.398657 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: da761833-f790-4248-be63-35af05edd62e) to Async(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_created_for_user", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0f006b058 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/53bab636-a567-4330-8189-7c27f6317423>>
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.402505 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 01e7deb2-667f-4adb-ac08-ea1c352b2afc) to Async(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_created_for_organizer", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0f007a0a8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/53bab636-a567-4330-8189-7c27f6317423>>
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.409284 #1] DEBUG -- :   Participation Load (4.9ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "53bab636-a567-4330-8189-7c27f6317423"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.412415 #1] DEBUG -- :   Participation Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "53bab636-a567-4330-8189-7c27f6317423"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.417211 #1] DEBUG -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b]    (9.6ms)  COMMIT
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.419007 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] Redirected to https://url-hidden.tld/events/e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.419482 #1]  INFO -- : [b857cc76-0b04-4eb0-a966-831e6f96164b] Completed 302 Found in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 17.2ms)
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.795879 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3] Started GET "/events/e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1" for client-ip-hidden at 2019-11-08 13:43:39 +0000
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.798061 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3] Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.798312 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Parameters: {"id"=>"e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"}
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.805128 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Event Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.809827 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.813428 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   CACHE Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.818056 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Participation Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 AND "participations"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $3  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["user_id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.820168 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Rendering events/show.html.erb within layouts/application
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.824740 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "35b6dc95-8805-4f8c-a029-9bcdbc75d4ab"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.840989 #1] DEBUG -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   User Exists (2.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "participations" ON "users"."id" = "participations"."user_id" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.849210 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Rendered events/_participation_form.html.erb (5.4ms)
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.849904 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3]   Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (29.3ms)
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:43:39.852692 #1]  INFO -- : [917f317e-3322-4ff9-b15d-8133727c71b3] Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 29.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
```

However when the mail gets send, this is what the logs look like:

```
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.118430 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] Started DELETE "/participations/6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664" for 186.150.163.227 at 2019-11-08 13:42:53 +000
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.121899 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] Processing by ParticipationsController#destroy as HTML                                                               
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.122101 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"token-hidden==", "id"=>"6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664"}                                                                                                                                                          
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.127654 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   Participation Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1 ORDER
 BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                        
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.132057 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   Event Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["
id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                        
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.136910 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id",
 "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                            
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.140319 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]    (0.8ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                    
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.143026 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   Participation Destroy (1.4ms)  DELETE FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1  [["id", "6a501ff1-753
f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664"]]                                                                                                                                                                                        
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.144966 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d) to Async(mailers) with 
arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_deleted_for_user", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0ee73fc00 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664>>                            
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.148786 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407) to Async(mailers) with 
arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_deleted_for_organizer", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0ee7af168 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e4664>>                       
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.156303 #1] DEBUG -- :   Participation Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-7
89ba66e4664"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                                                       
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.158944 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c42
8690d) from Async(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_deleted_for_user", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0ed7ef4a8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba66e46
64>>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.165183 #1] DEBUG -- :   Participation Load (9.7ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-7
89ba66e4664"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                         
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.165953 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]    (13.5ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                  
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.172472 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d]   User Load (7.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 O
RDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                    
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.168476 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d
29407) from Async(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "participation_deleted_for_organizer", "deliver_now", #<GlobalID:0x000055a0ef36ba60 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my-site/Participation/6a501ff1-753f-440e-b8ae-789ba
66e4664>>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.177900 #1] DEBUG -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915]   Participation Load (6.4ms)  SELECT "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 
ORDER BY created_at ASC  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"]]                                                                                                                                    
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.184385 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] Redirected to https://url-hidden.tld/events/e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1                                
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.185494 #1]  INFO -- : [897267b8-7fca-44e1-9005-b6a4ac050915] Completed 302 Found in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 26.2ms)                                                                   
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.186211 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407]   User Load (4.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 O
RDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                    
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.182691 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d]   Event Load (5.9ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = 
$1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.199605 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d]   Rendering user_mailer/participation_deleted_for_user.html.erb within layout
s/mailer                                                                                                                                                                                                           
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.202721 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d]   Rendered user_mailer/participation_deleted_for_user.html.erb within layouts
/mailer (2.6ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.206120 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d] UserMailer#participation_deleted_for_user: processed outbound mail in 44.1ms 
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.211154 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407]   Event Load (17.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" =
 $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                               
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.219013 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407]   User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 O
RDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "35b6dc95-8805-4f8c-a029-9bcdbc75d4ab"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                    
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.222833 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407]   Rendering user_mailer/participation_deleted_for_organizer.html.erb within l
ayouts/mailer                                                                                                                                                                                                      
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.224182 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407]   Rendered user_mailer/participation_deleted_for_organizer.html.erb within la
youts/mailer (1.1ms)                                                                                                                                                                                               
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.225554 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407] UserMailer#participation_deleted_for_organizer: processed outbound mail in 46
.6ms                                                                                                                                                                                                               
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.399392 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20] Started GET "/events/e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1" for 186.150.163.227 at 2019-11-08 13:42:53 +0000          
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.402341 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20] Processing by EventsController#show as HTML                                                                          
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.402654 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Parameters: {"id"=>"e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"}                                                         
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.409992 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Event Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["
id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                        
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.414408 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id",
 "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                            
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.418166 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   CACHE Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $
2  [["id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                  
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.423309 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Participation Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "participations".* FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1
 AND "participations"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $3  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["user_id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                   
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.426113 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Rendering events/show.html.erb within layouts/application                                                          
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.430863 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT $2  [["id",
 "35b6dc95-8805-4f8c-a029-9bcdbc75d4ab"], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                            
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.449615 #1] DEBUG -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   User Exists (3.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "participations" ON "users"."id" = "participations"."
user_id" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", "e2f59423-29b4-4538-8d6b-1365f9646ea1"], ["id", "07ac78fc-8394-406e-84c4-cbbdd4ba01ef"], ["LIMIT", 1]]               
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.456201 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Rendered events/_participation_form.html.erb (5.2ms)                                                               
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.458719 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20]   Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (32.2ms)                                                  
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:53.463384 #1]  INFO -- : [e0d373af-c11f-47ba-a870-c6870ea7db20] Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 32.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:54.194980 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407] Sent mail to target@hidden.tld (968.9ms)                           
app_1  | D, [2019-11-08T13:42:54.195461 #1] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [72e3b7cc-8a8c-4931-8d4f-4fe438d29407] Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 13:42:53 +0000                                        
app_1  | From: origin@hidden.tld                                                                                                                                                                                  
app_1  | To: target@hidden.tld                                                                                                                                                                           
app_1  | Message-ID: <5dc570dd37a24_12ad0773c450c46858@923cfdfbef0e.mail>                                                                                                                                          
app_1  | Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Teilnahme_gel=C3=B6scht?=                                                                                                                                                              
app_1  | Mime-Version: 1.0                                                                                                                                                                                         
app_1  | Content-Type: text/html;                                                                                                                                                                                  
app_1  |  charset=UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                                            
app_1  | Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable     
[mail contents here]
app_1  | I, [2019-11-08T13:42:54.590292 #1]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c428690d] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8c4fbe13-cd6e-45e5-b694-e395c42$
690d) from Async(mailers) in 1430.6ms
```

As can be seen, when the delivery fails, the mail job gets enqueued but never sent. This happens occasionally, however sometimes it will not sent anymore at all until server restart. There is no error message.

Comment: Do you see any error on feedback on the logs?

Comment: I'm wondering if you are receiving an error on one of the emails that is delivered later that is causing the entire process to end.  Are you on a linux system?  Can you search the logs?  /var/log/mailog; /var/log/mail.log; /var/adm/mailog; /var/adm/syslog/mail.log; /etc/syslog.conf are likely locations.

Comment: I edited to include the logs. Yes it's a Linux system, but I deliver using SMTP to gmail, thus I do not expect to see them in the Linux mail logs (correct me if I'm wrong).